# qsharp.reload() throws error in python

Tags: programming, q#

I'm trying to add the Q# machine learning library to my program by

```
import qsharp
qsharp.packages.add("Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825")
qsharp.reload()
```

but it throws the errors below. Any solutions?

P.S. I have the qsharp package and iqsharp installed. Normal programs in python that use qsharp work correctly.

```
dotnet iqsharp --version
iqsharp: 0.11.2006.403
Jupyter Core: 1.3.60623.0
.NET Runtime: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
```

and

```
'iqsharp': LooseVersion ('0.11.2006.403'),
 'Jupyter Core': LooseVersion ('1.3.60623.0'),
 '.NET Runtime': LooseVersion ('.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'),
 'qsharp': LooseVersion ('0.11.2006.403')
```

Also even if I don't add the Machine Learning library and just run

```
import qsharp
qsharp.reload()
```

It still throws the same error

Errors:

```
Adding package Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IQSharpError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b3244a777be2> in <module>
      1 import qsharp
      2 qsharp.packages.add("Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning::0.11.2004.2825")
----> 3 qsharp.reload()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qsharp\__init__.py in reload()
     70     Q# compilation errors are raised as an exception.
     71     """
---> 72     client.reload()
     73 
     74 def get_available_operations() -> List[str]:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qsharp\clients\iqsharp.py in reload(self)
    117 
    118     def reload(self) -> None:
--> 119         return self._execute(f"%workspace reload", raise_on_stderr=True)
    120 
    121     def add_package(self, name : str) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qsharp\clients\iqsharp.py in _execute(self, input, return_full_result, raise_on_stderr, output_hook, **kwargs)
    207         # There should be either zero or one execute_result messages.
    208         if errors:
--> 209             raise IQSharpError(errors)
    210         if results:
    211             assert len(results) == 1

IQSharpError: The Q# kernel raised the following errors:
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(2,10): error QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Convert" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(3,10): error QS6104: No namespace with the name "Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(60,21): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Default" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(61,16): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Structure" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(62,16): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Parameters" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(63,16): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Bias" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(11,16): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Length" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(30,23): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Mapped" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(32,13): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Zip" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(35,13): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Mapped" exists.
    C:/Users/Shreyas/Documents/jupyter/Quantum/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/MLADS2020-QuantumClassification-master/test/Operation.qs(46,9): error QS5022: No identifier with the name "Message" exists.
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `dotnet iqsharp --version` at the command line, or `qsharp.component_versions()` from within Python? That would help us to diagnose your error much better. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ChrisGranade Please check the edited post... I added the versions. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! It looks like your IQ# version is 0.11.2006.403, but you're trying to add version 0.11.2004.2825 of the Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning package. I'd suggest either downgrading IQ# to 0.11.2004.2825, or modifying the `qsharp.packages.add` call to use 0.11.2006.403.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisGranade! That solved my problem.

Comment: No worries, happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChrisGranade [solved my problem](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/qsharp-reload-throws-error-in-python#comment16425_12466):

> It looks like your IQ# version is 0.11.2006.403, but you're trying to add version 0.11.2004.2825 of the Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning package. I'd suggest either downgrading IQ# to 0.11.2004.2825, or modifying the `qsharp.packages.add` call to use 0.11.2006.403